# Vault policy path with wildcard

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I've below policy in vault

```
path "/secrets/global/*" { capabilities = ["read", "create", "update", "delete", "list"] }
```

will this policy grant me access to all the paths under global like

```
/secrets/global/common/*
/secrets/global/notsocommoon/app1/*
/secrets/global/notsocommoon/app1/module1/*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Vault will grand **all the capabilities** to the `/secrets/global/` and its child directory.

As we can add multiple paths to the same policy, if we want to **restrict few capabilities** a particular path, we can do that like

```
#mypolicy.hcl
path "/secrets/global/*" { capabilities = ["read", "create", "update", "delete", "list"] } 

path "/secrets/global/myteam/passwords/*" { capabilities = ["read"] }
```